# $(...).dropzone is not a function when using dropzone with browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, dropzone.js

I would like to know how to use dropzone with browserify. I use it in the most naive way but in vain.

```
var dropzone = require('dropzone');
var $ = require('jquery');

$('div#form').dropzone({ url: '/form' });
```

I ve got a warning saying $(...).dropzone is not a function.

Can anyone point me a way out?

Brian

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```js
var jQuery = require('jquery');
var dropzone = require('dropzone');

jQuery('div#form').dropzone({ url: '/form' });
```

Dropzone script check the type of jQuery, so you should define jQuery(but not $) and firstly you should difine jQuery and just after it Dropzone